# store selected rows on PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a tableview that is of type PFQueryTableViewController and gets its value from Parse cloud. The tableview works fine but now I need to allow the user to:

- Select a row
- Record in a column (string array) on Parse-Users table what rows have been selected (need to record on parse that - i will use these values for other things later)
- When the user comes back and opens the tableview he can see what rows have been selected last time he was in the app

I am not sure if PFQueryTableViewController has any methods ready for that. Could anyone give me some guidance?

I would prefer to use parse cause there are so much stuff out of the box. But if not, that is fine as well.

Also, code samples from similar solutions would be great. Just need to know the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table view controller is there for display, it will tell you about selection, but it won't automatically maintain a record of selected items in the back end. You need to decide on the appropriate way to store the selections (array of pointers is better than an array of strings) and update the store and table display appropriately. There is no standard approach to this.